# Motor transport vs Motorized transport

Tags: differences

What is the difference between "motor transport" and "motorized transport". The dictionaries do not contain these collocations and relevant explanations.

Are they interchangeable? As I understand, motorized transport and motor transport mean the vehicles fitted with an engine.

Comment: *Motor transport* simply refers to transport by something that contains a motor. Strictly-speaking, *motor**ized** transport* also includes the idea that the conveyance has undergone some process resulting in it having a motor. (Consider other -ized words like *up-sized*, *pulverized*, etc - they carry the sense of something having undergone a process.) However, in common usage, your two phrases are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

It might help to understand the grammatical terminology behind the two alternatives.

In *motorized transport*, *motorized* obviously is an **adjective** modifying the noun *transport*. In *motor transport*, *motor* is called a **noun adjunct** or **attributive noun**, much like in *chicken soup* or *football player* and is used in the same way as adjectives are.

While there are no common alternatives using adjectives instead of attributive nouns in compounds like *football player* there often is more than one way of expressing something. On its entry to attributive noun wikipedia gives the example that both *erythrocyte maturation* (attributive noun) and *erythrocytic maturation* (adjective) are common and valid terms for the same process. Thus, the availability of a valid adjective does not necesarrily need to keep you from using an attributive noun in its place.

That said, I would consider both alternatives, *motor transport* and *motorized transport* as equally valid synonyms.

Comment: I think it's true that they're both valid, and I completely agree with your analysis, but I think it's worth pointing out that "motorized transport" sounds quite archaic, and I think the reason is that it begs the question "compared to what?".  IE, what unmotorized transport might we be talking about?  Bicycles and walking don't seem appropriate - it sounds more like the things that were superseded by motorized transport, namely horses and horse-driven coaches.  "Motor transport" seems like a more simple term as it doesn't sound like an alternative to something last seen in bulk 100 years ago.

Answer (score -1):

I completely agree, both motor transport and motorized transport are regarded as identical synonyms. These are regarded so by Google and various other search engines.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that this is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site; to support an existing answer, you would use the voting arrows associated with it. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.