# Functional vs. function

Tags: adjectives

I often see "functional" used as an adjective in situations where I think that "function" would actually be the better choice.
Specifically, I am referring to translations of German compound nouns.

Here is an example: Funktionsarchitektur. This is the architecture of the function/functions. To be specific, we are talking about a technical function in a machine or vehicle. This is the architecture of the devices, control units, etc. which perform the specific function. ABS would be one example.

In this case I would use "function architecture", translating it as a compound noun in English as well. For me, "functional architecture" is an architecture which functions and not an architecture of/for functions.

I see a lot of cases in which the adjective "functional" is used instead of expanding the compound noun.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: architecture of the function? Surely, the correct translation is: functional architecture as opposed to whimsical architecture, decorative architecture, etc. "the architecture of a function" means you are showing the structure of the function, which would be quite unusual.

Comment: Yes; there is often a case for choosing the attributive noun rather than the related adjective, or vice versa. They're often only broadly synonymous. 'Functional' does default to the 'working / useful' senses ... **in general usage**. But here, isn't this computerese? Can the term have a different sense? This will sway the default reading.  But collocation is often unpredictable, illogical. You can only determine which is the better choice in context by researching standard practice _in the relevant domain_.

Comment: My bad. I wasn't specific enough and have edited my post to explain what is actually meant by "Funktionsarchitecture" - Namey, the technical architecture of a function in a vehicle or machine. ABS or a lane-keeping assistant would be two examples.

Comment: "technical architecture of a function" makes no sense.

Comment: Now we're having fun! The way this technical development is broken down, they actually have a function level, a higher-order system level, a sub-systems leven and then, finally, a component level. The component architecture is actually something completely different to the function architecture.

This is actually part of the challenge - The company has some very strict terminology standards, yet simultaneously loopholes like this.

as @psmears pointed out that functional programming means "programming related to/using/founded on functions" - That clarified the issue for me.

Comment: There's a similar question about [grammar v grammatical](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/512836/adjective-vs-noun-as-an-adjective), [ancestor v ancestral](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/595784/how-do-an-attributive-noun-noun-adjunct-and-an-adjective-differ-in-the-case-wh), [motor vs motorised](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/266704/motor-transport-vs-motorized-transport), etc.

Answer (score 2):

The word *functional* is [defined](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/functional), among other definitions, as:

> of, connected with, or being a function

in addition to the meaning you allude to of

> performing or able to perform a regular function

So "functional architecture") *can* refer to architecture relating to functions, and does not have to mean "architecture that functions".

A similar phrase from another discipline is [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming), which very much means "programming related to/using/founded on functions", rather than "programming which works".

Comment: You have to scroll a long way down the senses listed in dictionaries prioritising idiomaticity before you get to this sense. Assuming they carry it at all. I'd wager OED carries an 'observe with a telescope' sense for the verb 'telescope'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I mean, it's sense 1a in the dictionary I linked to. Granted it's far from the most common meaning, especially if you're not used to encountering it in technical contexts, but equally it's not _that_ obscure!

Comment: But you're on a loser with M-W as regards ordering wrt frequency of use of senses; like OED, it's a historical dictionary. Granted, in some cases dictionaries seem to list in order of 'closest meaning to related noun' etc, whatever they claim about their protocols.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Yeah not claiming that first position means most frequently used!

Comment: Good point with "functional programming".

I see similar usage with phrases like "functional overview" where I would be more inclined to write "function overview" (opting for brevity instead of writing "Overview of the functions").

My brain just insists that "functional" means "something that functions".